# Does the order of keys in dictionary.keys() in a python dictionary change if the values are changed?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a python dictionary (say dict) in which I keep modifying values (the keys remain unaltered). Will the order of keys in the list given by dict.keys() change when I modify the values corresponding to the keys?

Comment: By "modifying values" do you mean assigning a new value to a key (e.g., `d['key'] = newVal`) or mutating an existing value object (e.g., `d['key'].append(1)`)?

Comment: The order, once set does not change. However dicts do not have an order in which the keys are stored

Comment: I am doing both, assigning a new value, and mutating it.

Comment: Even if the order doesnt appear to change it should not be relied upon.  The behaviour you see is a side effect of implemetation. Jython, pypy etc may not behave the same. For gaurunteed preservation of order you should look at using OrderedDict.

Comment: Do you need an ordered dict, or are you just wondering? What is the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: why do you need ordering in dict ?

Answer (score 2):

No, a python dictionary has an ordering for the keys but does not guarantee what that order will be or how it is calculated.
Which is why they are not guaranteed to be ordered in the first place.
The values stored in the dictionary do not have an effect on the hash values of the keys and so will not change ordering.

Taken from the [Python Documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries):

> **The keys() method of a dictionary object returns a list of all the keys used in the dictionary, in arbitrary order** (if you want it sorted, just apply the sorted() function to it). To check whether a single key is in the dictionary, use the in keyword.

Answer (score 1):

No, the order of the dict will not change because you change the values. The order depends on the keys only (or their hash value, to be more specific at least in CPython). However, it may change between versions and implementations of Python, and in Python 3.3, it will change every time you start Python.

Answer (score 0):

Python dictionaries' key ordering should not be assumed constant.

However, there are other datastructures that do give consistent key ordering, that work a lot like dictionaries:

http://stromberg.dnsalias.org/~strombrg/treap/

http://stromberg.dnsalias.org/~strombrg/red-black-tree-mod/

BTW, you should not name a variable "dict", because there is a builtin type called "dict" that will be made invisible.